# Harry Potter fan fiction where Lucius, Voldemort and Harry are friends and demons

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I read that fan fiction a year ago on Fanficion.net and I cannot find it again.

This is about Lucius and Voldemort being the mate of Harry Potter. They are demons. I remember that all of the founders are in it too and they are demons too. Also many things happen in the Chamber of Secrets.

Harry became friends with his year mate Slytherins. Also Harry is a little stupid and demands things from Voldemort and Lucius he shouldn't then Lucius go away then came back so Harry won't die.

Comment: [This one](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/11544624/1/The-Mate-Bond) ??

Comment: I've edited to make this clearer in a few places but there were some sentences that weren't easy to decipher what you meant so I left them alone to avoid confusion. Could you [edit] it to try and be a bit clearer? For example, what does _"Also Harry is a little stupid and demands things from Voldemort and Lucius he shouldn't then Lucius go away then came back so Harry won't die."_ mean?

Comment: @the I think it means Harry made stupid demands from them, things he shouldn't have asked, and after that its explaining some different plot point; Lucius goes away but comes back later to save Harry

Comment: @user13267 That's the most likely explanation but it isn't 100% clear and could do with some more explanation anyway i.e. what are those demands, are the two things actually connected, why does Lucius have to go away etc.

Comment: Friends and fiends...